# Where do i find the code behind for a drupal 6 menu?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I have just taken over a drupal 6 website and need to change a link from an image.

the image is a menu item , but that menu items Path does not change when i change it in the backend. I assume the whole file has been over written but i am not sure where to find this file. I have looked in the "Bartik" themes file with all the .tpl.php files but i cant find anything.

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core code behind menu is in **includes/menu.inc**, you have a problem if someone have overwritten the initial logic there.

The first thing to know about Drupal is — do not override core behavior.

The primary theme functions, involved in menu rendering are:

- `theme_menu_item` Generate the HTML output for a menu item and
  submenu.
- `theme_menu_item_link`    Generate the HTML output for a single
  menu link.
- `theme_menu_tree` Generate the HTML output for a menu tree

I would recommend to check the source first on [api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includesmenu.inc/6](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/6)

If none of above makes sense, please check [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/55126) article to learn, how to override theme functions.

Comment: wow .. I am so confused. I am not sure why this all cant be edited in the cms itself. It seems like all the pages are new .tpl.php pages. I am not sure that the includes/menu.inc was overwrittern but that did answer my question , so thanks.

Comment: @gerdi There is a variety of ways to implement a menu in Drupal, if you do it right, you can interact with it from the Admin Panel, but this is something that you have to find out.

Comment: Yeah i did find it in the admin menu but it was just a link with the path input field pointing to a url that i dont want to point it to , when i changed that nothing happened it still pointed to the other url. I flushed all caches and refreshed the browser still nothing. Im not sure, will just have to dig deeper

Comment: @gerdi my only guess is that someone has hard-coded the link somewhere, try searching the URL through the project files. If you can't find it there, then you'll need to check the database. In Drupal you can create blocks with custom HTML content, there is a chance, that you might find it there.